# rails_helper.rb file (tests pass even if I don`t require it)

Tags: rspec, tdd

I've got a question, concerning the file rails_helper.rb that Rspec generates. I´ve got it all working really well, but there is something that I don`t get. I know what has to go into that file (the support directory, the database cleaner..). And I´ve seen at least hundreds examples of people requiring that file into there feature, model and controller tests.

Consider this example that I have in my app:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe User do

  it "is valid with valid attributes" do
    user = build(:user)
    expect(user).to be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid when username is blank" do
    user = build(:user, username: "")
    expect(user).to_not be_valid
  end 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          it "is invalid when username is too long" do
    user = build(:user, username: "a" * 21)
    expect(user).to_not be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid when username is too short" do
    user = build(:user, username: "a" * 3)
    expect(user).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

And if I just remove the "require_helper.rb" - nothing happens? The tests still pass? And I´ve got some 20 tests where I remove that line, they still pass (in some I´ve tried to use directly the ActiveRecord models without factory girl and it still passes)!

Im using: factory_girl, database cleaner, rspec 3 and rails 4.2

Is there something that I´m missing? Shouldn't there be an error of somekind?

Tnx,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Does the project have a `.rspec` file in the root? That is often used to automatically require the RSpec helper.

Comment: yes there is an .rspec file, but it only includes spec_helper.rb. The rails_helper.rb should load the entire rails stack, but the spec_helper.rb is for all the non rails classes (at least thats what I read).

Comment: Does your project use Spring? If you prefix the rspec commmand with `DISABLE_SPRING=1` do you see the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes you're right, it was because of spring (sorry forgot to mention that I use it). Just disabled it and rails is complaining that it can't resolve constant User. Tnx Andy :)